# Writing features in GML format

Tags: openlayers, gml

I would like to use OpenLayers 3 to write [GML features](http://openlayers.org/en/latest/apidoc/ol.format.GML.html).

Here is my code:

```
proj4.defs("EPSG:25833", "+proj=utm +zone=33 +ellps=GRS80 +towgs84=0,0,0,0,0,0,0 +units=m +no_defs");

prjCrs.epsg25832 = ol.proj.get('EPSG:25832');
prjCrs.epsg4326 = 'EPSG:4326';


var features = digitizingVector.getSource().getFeatures();

var format = new ol.format.GML();
var out = format.writeFeatures(features, {
    dataProjection: prjCrs.epsg4326,
    featureProjection: prjCrs.epsg25832
});
```

However, this always spits out the following error message:

```
ol.js:357 Uncaught TypeError: Cannot read property 'undefined' of undefined
```

With `ol-debug.js` the following error message is returned:

[image]

I am using the exact same logic to write features in GeoJSON, KML, GPX, WKT and it works perfecty fine. Is there an issue with GML features in OpenLayers 3?

I am using version **3.19.1** of OpenLayers.

Comment: What is the error message when using ol-debug.js ?

Comment: Thank you, I have updated my question accordingly. I also mentioned that I am using version **3.19.1**.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

When writing out GML you need to provide some extra config in the constructor of the format, probably featureType, featureNS and srsName.

Comment: That worked! All of the above had to be entered: featureNS, featureType, srsName.

Comment: What surprise me is that featureNS, featureType and srsName are optional but there is an error in JS if there are not defined.